# What is the appropriate NLP model to generate paraphrased sentences of a specific form?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

So my problem is actually quite simple: I have a set of sentences all of a very similar structure and another set of sentences that have basically the same meaning (but not quite as the example shows), but expressed differently eg: "Go get 10 apples", "I have gone and got 10 apples", and I would like a way to reliably convert a sentence of type 1 to its type 2 counterpart (given that the type 1 sentence is a never-before-seen user input)

Now, since this is not quite paraphrasing I am struggling to figure out the correct model/approach to use for achieving this task. It could obviously be done using GPT-J, GPT-neo etc, but these seem way too heavy for this small and specific task that I am trying to achieve.

I am hoping that there are some already pretrained models that could achieve this easily, but if not and I have to generate my own dataset and train my own model, then at least I know my effort is not getting wasted.

Any reccomendations?